# Nginx не дает грузить файлы со стороннего ресурса

Tags: nginx

Перенес сайт на  https. После этого все картинки на сайте которые грузятся по http не отображаются. Пишет следующую ошибку в консоли

```
This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

Вот конфиг

```
upstream puma {
  server unix:///home/deploy/apps/rifc/shared/tmp/sockets/rifc-puma.sock;
}


# Редирект с www.xxx.su.com на xxx.su.com при любом протоколе
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name www.xxx.su;
  return 301 $scheme://xxx.su$request_uri;
}

# Редирект с http на https
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name xxx.su;
  return 301 https://xxx.su$request_uri;
}


server {
  listen 443 ssl http2;
  server_name xxx.su;
  rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 permanent;

  client_max_body_size 4G;
  keepalive_timeout 10;
  root /home/deploy/apps/rifc/current/public;
  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  try_files $uri @puma;

  add_header Content-Security-Policy "block-all-mixed-content";
  add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains";
  add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
  add_header X-Frame-Options DENY;
  resolver 127.0.0.1 8.8.8.8;
  ssl on;
  ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
  ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
  ssl_session_timeout 5m;
  ssl_stapling on;
  ssl_stapling_verify on;
  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/xxx.su/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/xxx.su/privkey.pem;
  ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/xxx.su/chain.pem;

  location @puma{
    access_log /home/deploy/apps/rifc/current/log/nginx.access.log;
    error_log /home/deploy/apps/rifc/current/log/nginx.error.log info;

    limit_req zone=one burst=3;
    proxy_pass  http://puma;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  }

  location /.well-known {
    root /var/www/html;
  }



  if ($request_method !~ ^(GET|HEAD|PUT|PATCH|POST|DELETE|OPTIONS)$ ){
    return 405;
  }
}
```

Как решить эту проблему?

Comment: У вас ошибка в какой консоли отображается, браузера? И запросы у вас идут от браузера на сторонние ресурсы? Если да, тогда причем тут ваш nginx? Меняйте все ссылки на вашем сайте на https. Если сторонние сайты не работают на https, то копируйте файлы к себе на сервер.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас типичная проблема mixed content. Все должно отображаться, только браузер не выставляет зеленый замочек, пока вы не переведете все ресурсы на https.

А не отображается потому, что вы дали nginx инструкцию "block-all-mixed-content". Уберите эту строчку, начнут картинки отображаться. Потом постепенно переводите все ресурсы на https, чтобы получить доверенный сайт.

Comment: Сделал как вы сказали -убрал block-all-mixed content

Comment: Тоже самое.....

Comment: Покажите сайт...

Comment: ну и что вы убрали? ничего вы не убрали: http://take.ms/LN9Ix

Comment: #add_header Content-Security-Policy "block-all-mixed-content"; закоментил

Comment: только что.....

Comment: Кажись заработало) а чем это чревато?

Comment: ничем, кроме небольшого падения рейтинга сайта. Гугл такое не очень любит. Возьмите картинку с внешнего ресурса, скопируйте себе и значок будет зеленым.

Comment: И в качестве совета: уберите эту дурацкую картинку Secure Site. Зеленый замок в адресной строке браузера гораздо весомее ))

Comment: спасибо!) вчера решил проверить сайт на уязвимости -сегодня убрал уже его

Comment: Если ответ полезен, его стоит отметить как принятый галочкой внизу. Это поможет ориентироваться пользователям, которые ищут ответ на подобный вопрос.